# \ > 'com.android.build.api.variant.SourceDirectories$Flat com.android.build.api.variant.Sources.getByName(java.lang.String)'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I am working on a flutter project with android module. when running the app, I am getting the following error
**> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> 'com.android.build.api.variant.SourceDirectories$Flat com.android.build.api.variant.Sources.getByName(java.lang.String)'**

I tried everthing, from updating gradle to com.android.tools.build:gradle 8.2.2 to updating to java 17 and changing the kotlin version to 1.9.20

What could be the problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am having the same problem, can you please share more details